# Помогите разобраться с MinGW C++

Tags: c++, mingw

Работаю в CodeBlocks. Подключено несколько библиотек. Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы моя программа запускалась на компьютерах без MinGW?

Comment: Приложить к приложению все необходимые библиотеки перед распространением (просто так или пакетным менеджером). Ну или слинковать их статически.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь) Разобрался.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут скорее дубликаты в дубликаты

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, ну так дубликат ты не предлагал...

Comment: @Qwertiy ща в самолете, интернет очень уж дорогой искать